# How to create new variable instance with useState (React Hook) each time a user fires a specific action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm new to React and JS. I want to create **a new distinct** variable that will use the State Hook **each time** the user uploads a file via a form. How can I achieve this kind of functionality?
I have tried naming the variables with eval() to obtain the dynamic naming but it doesn't work well in React

Answer (score 1):

I think you use an object or an array :

Array

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const addNewfile = (newFile) => {
  setFiles(prev => [...prev, newFile];
}
```

Object

```js
const [files, setFiles] = useState({});

const addNewfile = (newFile) => {
  setFiles(prev => ({...prev, [newFile.name]: newFile});
}
```